# How can I add a date to my html calendar?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calendar, which shows meetings, and i want to make a function to do that. Basically, I'm trying to make a function addMeeting(day, month), which would make the meeting date background-color yellow. Here's the non-working function:

```
function addMeeting(day, month) {
  if (date.getMonth() == month-1) {
      renderCalendar();
      document.querySelector("monthDays:nth-child(day+document.querySelectorAll('.prev-date').length)").css("background-color", "yellow");
        renderCalendar();
  };
};
```

Where `date.getMonth();` is the month index (0-11), and `renderCalendar();` renders the calendar, but the following part isn't working:

```
document.querySelector("monthDays:nth-child(day+document.querySelectorAll('.prev-date').length)").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: "where date.getMonth();  is the month index (0-11) renderCalendar(); renders the calendar, but the document.querySelector("monthDays:nth-child(day+document.querySelectorAll('.prev-date').length)").css("background-color", "yellow");` part isn't working."

                                                                                                                                 
       Somehow I messed that part up, hope you can undestand still

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function addMeeting(day, month){
      if (date.getMonth() == month-1){
          renderCalendar();
          document.querySelector("monthDays:nth-child(" + (day+document.querySelectorAll('.prev-date').length)+")").css("background-color", "yellow");
            renderCalendar();
      };
    };
```

Comment: `:nth-child(day2)` is not a valid selector.

Comment: I would also question why `date` appears to be undefined. And why `renderCalendar()` is called twice. And many other things like how the HTML structure seems to be tied so strongly to functionality. And I doubt there's a `<monthDays>` tag.

Comment: have fixed it, you need to pass a index vale to the nth-child (day+length(2))

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol: I have declared it: const monthDays = document.querySelector('.days'); and I have made a div class named days

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null